# Lisp IF-THEN-ELSE Lambda Calc Implementation

Tags: lisp, lambda-calculus

I made this IF-THEN-ELSE Lambda Calculus code

```
(defvar IF-THEN-ELSE
    #'(lambda(con)
        #'(lambda(x)
            #'(lambda(y)
                #'(lambda(acc1)
                    #'(lambda (acc2)
                        (funcall (funcall (funcall (funcall con x) y) acc1) acc2))))))
)

(defun IF-THEN-ELSEOP(c x y a1 a2)
    (funcall (funcall (funcall (funcall (funcall IF-THEN-ELSE c) x) y) a1) a2)
)
```

And this Greater or Equal operator

```
(defvar GEQ
    #'(lambda(p)
        #'(lambda(q)
              (funcall #'LEQOP q p)))
)
```

LEQOP is a function for "Less or Equal" and it works OK. So when I call IF-THEN-ELSE like this ("six" and "two" are church numbers)

```
(if-then-elseop GEQ six two (print "THIS") (print "THAT"))
```

as output I've got

```
"THIS" 
"THAT" 
"THIS"
```

Both functions that I'm passing are being called. How can I avoid it in order to get only as output "THIS"?

This happens with every function I use, and this is a trouble because I want to use IF-THEN-ELSE in a recursive call, so just one function must be called dependign on the IF-THEN-ELSE eval.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Passing your `print` statements by wrapping them in `lambda`s should work, but maybe it's worth an explanation as to why this is necessary.

You're implementing a lambda calculus. By definition, all 'things' in the calculus are *higher order functions*. Your `six` and `two` and any other church numerals you may have defined are also higher order functions.

`IF-THEN-ELSE` is a lambda *abstraction* (also a higher-order function because it's 'arguments' are also functions). So this would have been valid:

```
(if-then-elseop GEQ six two one two)
```

Where `one` and `two` are church numbers. By doing that, you're expressing in lambda calculus what you would in plain lisp as:

```
(if (>= 6 2) 
  1 
  2)
```

But I'm guessing what you were aiming for was:

```
(if (>= 6 2) 
  (print "this")
  (print "that"))
```

*(more later about why messing with `print` might be a distraction to your exercise)*

So the 'real' `1` has a church encoding `one`, which I'me assuming you've defined. That way, it can be *applied* to the lambda abstraction `IF-THEN-ELSE` - In the same way that

```
(>= 6 2)
```

evaluates to TRUE in the *lisp world*, your lambda calculus implementation of the same,

```
((GEQ six) two)
```

will evaluate to the *lambda encoding of TRUE*, which is again, encoded as a higher-order function.

```
(defvar TRUE #'(lambda (x) #'(lambda (y) x)))
(defvar FALSE #'(lambda (x) #'(lambda (y) y)))
```

So the rule to remember is that everything you are passing around and getting back in the lambda calculus are *functions*:

```
 0 := λf.λx.x             
 1 := λf.λx.f x
 2 := λf.λx.f (f x)
 3 := λf.λx.f (f (f x))
 ... and so on
```

Which is why, if you did:

```
(if-then-elseop GEQ six two 
   #'(lambda () (print "THIS"))
   #'(lambda () (print "THAT")))
```

should work. *(sort of, read ahead)*

(I'd stick to the faithful interpretation of `IF-THEN-ELSE` though:

```
(defvar IFTHENELSE 
  #'(lambda (p) 
    #'(lambda (a) 
      #'(lambda (b) (funcall (funcall p a) b)))))
```

Where `p` is your condition... )

As a side note, it's worth pointing out that it might not be too helpful to bring in `print` and other code that 'does stuff' within lambda calculus - the calculus does not define IO, and is restricted to evaluation of lambda expressions. The church encodings are a way of encoding numbers as *lambda terms*; There's no simple and meaningful way to represent 
a *statement with side-effects* such a `(print "hello")` as a lambda term; `#'(lambda () (print "THIS"))` works but as an academic exercise it's best to stick to only evaluating things and getting back results.

What about *lisp itself*? `if` in lisp is not a function so `(if cond then-expr else-expr)` works the way you expect (that is, only one of `then-expr` or `else-expr` will actually be evaluated) because it is a *special form*. If you were to define your own, you would need a *macro* (as @wvxvw rightly suggests). But that's another topic.